# Java shell expansion similar to wordexp

Tags: java, linux, filesystems

Is there a way to do shell wildcard expansion in java similar to the way that the C function call *wordexp* works? It seems a bit platform specific, but there has to be a nice abstraction for this in one of the java system classes, right? I would be happy if I could get ~/, ./, and ../ to resolve to their canonical paths. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more extensive pattern support, take a look at `java.nio.file.Files`, in particular methods such as [`newDirectoryStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String)).  Search through the page for the word "glob".  There is more information in the Sun [File Operations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html) tutorial page.  (This flavour of 'globbing' supports `*`, `**`, `?`, `[...]` and `{...}`, but not `~`.)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to replace . and .., you may use [File.getCanonicalPath()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath())